# No se puede acceder al sitio web

Tags: html, google-chrome, https

Tengo una aplicacion web, en la cual hay archivos .jpeg alojados, los cuales están dentro de un carpeta llamada "albaranes"

Cuando intento abrir un archivo desde la url como por ejemplo:
www.miweb.com/albaranes/nombre_archivo.jpeg
Me salta la siguiente pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado que el archivo esté ahí, y sí. El archivo esta alojado con exactamente el mismo nombre.

Al intentar descargar el archivo me aparece lo que se ven en la imagen

Como puedo averiguar que es lo que está pasando?

Es una cosa que sólo me pasa hoy, me ha funcionado perfectamente desde hace 6 meses

Comment: Sin la URL correcta no sabremos si se trata de una defensa contra el *hotlinking* o una protección antibots (como las que usa cloudflare) en la que antes de abrir el contenido de un dominio hay que cargar una web que deje una "cookie" de validación. ¿Has probado a cargar primero una página válida antes de cargar la imagen?

Comment: He tapado la direccion URL completa ya que se tratan datos confidenciales. Tengo alojada la aplicacion dentro de www.miweb.com/avisos/index.php y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Aparte de lo que te comenta @OscarGarcia, revisa si en el archivo `.htaccess` de la carpeta `albaranes` (o en otro `.htaccess` de las carpetas anteriores) no hay redirecciones o restricciones para ver ciertos archivos como imágenes.

Comment: Acabo de comprobarlo desde Edge y funciona perfecto. El problema es de chrome, desde hace 6 meses funcionaba sin problemas y de repente ya no

Comment: Correcto, parece ser un problema de `Chrome`. [En este post](https://switchgeek.com/err-spdy-protocol-error/) dan algunas indicaciones para poder resolver el problema. Lo primero sería tener `Chrome` actualizado. Puede estar relacionado también con el antivirus, con certificados `https`, etc. [Revisa también aquí](https://zenguard.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204423722-Chrome-error-ERR-SPDY-PROTOCOL-ERROR-).

Comment: En mi caso ni tan siquiera carga la página web. He probado https://www.miweb.com/avisos/albaranes/18920.jpeg y http://www.miweb.com/avisos/albaranes/18920.jpeg sin éxito en ninguno de los casos (probado con firefox y chrome) con un error de conexión cerrada por el otro extremo.

Comment: la URL miweb.com es sólo un ejemplo, ya que no puedo proporcionaros la url real por motivos de datos confidenciales

Comment: @A.Cedano Funciona gracias a tu aporte, he borrado caché y cookies y ya por fin está solucionado. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro. Quizá habría sido conveniente poner los pasos que se indican en los dos posts enlazados en el comentario anterior, para que pueda servir a otros usuarios, pues puede que en algunos casos la solución pasa por otra(s) de las acciones indicadas.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, el error ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR se ha solucionado en Google Chrome borrando la caché y las cookies.